# Moving values to different Google Sheet without deleting original row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Current script, based on Kriggs' suggestions:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named All Projects
  // target sheet of move to named History
  // test column with yes/no is col 18 or R
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "All Projects" && r.getColumn() == 18 && r.getValue() == "Yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn() - 1;
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    range.clearContent();
  }
}
```

When I had the s.getRange set to 2, it was skipping a column and everything was off. I set it back to 1 (after unmerging the cells) and it worked.

However, it's not clearing. I thought that the range.clearContent would clear the range I just moved from All Projects, it looks like it does that in the original script. Do I need to call the original range again?

Also, this is copying over the formulas, instead of just the results. I'll be changing the data those cells reference (cells N4 and O4 in the History tab, for instance) and I want those to stay locked in.

Edited to add:

To clarify how I'm wanting to use this sheet: the purpose is to allow people (or me, really) to keep track of projects. Each line in the All Projects will populate a Project sheet of it's corresponding number. So I can have up to 10 projects on the go, and see the prices and genes needed for each. After a project is completed, I want to be able to archive the information (so I can feel proud about completing it) and then clear that project line out to have another project in there.

I know this question has been asked a few times, and I did read through those answers, but they all delete the source row at the end. They also just seem to move the data over, instead of the values.

[Here is a dummy version of my sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lUwM2pf-egOFpEaZ8nsH3tP19Es6Hh0F6PjCOii3cXg/edit?usp=sharing) Don't worry about that #REF!, it works in the full sheet.

I have a spreadsheet where 'All Projects' lets you choose your options for the project you want to do (say Project 1), which then populates the Project 1 sheet. When Project 1 is marked as 'completed' in the All Projects sheet, I'd like to have it either automatically move to the History sheet, or have a menu that the user could use.

In my head, I feel a menu will slow the sheet down less? It's not a very large or complex sheet, so it might not matter.

This was working when I first pasted it in and customised it to work with my data, but now I can NOT get it to work at all. I did remove one column, but I don't see how changing the 'Yes' from column S to R should break it, when I have it looking in column 18.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 18 or R
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "All Projects" && r.getColumn() == 18 && r.getValue() == "Yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    range.clearContent();
  }
}
```

Got the script from [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/hR40qh02UWE).

When this was working, I saw that this deletes the row. I tried to use the clearContent command since that's supposed to leave the formatting intact, but it just cleared everything including my data validation.

I think I should be using the clear(options) thing, but that didn't seem to work either.

[This](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/03/google-sheets-move-a-row-of-data-to-another-sheet-based-on-cell-value/) seems to be an updated version, but it moves the data depending on another variable, and I can't seem to untangle it all. It also deletes the row, and isn't grabbing the values.

[This](http://www.jacorre.com/tutorial/move-rows-between-google-sheets/) depends on people selecting rows and columns, and isn't an onEdit so all the things seem to be different. I tried this:

```
    function approveRequests() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
     sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
     sheetName = sheet.getName(),
     data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 var r = sheet.getActiveRange();

 if (sheetName == "All Projects"&& r.getColumn() == 19 && r.getValue() == "Yes") {
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange(),
      startRow = range.getRowIndex(),
      numRows = range.getNumRows(),
      numCols = range.getNumColumns()
    var values = range.getValues(),
        nextSheet = ss.getSheetByName("History"),
        lastRow = nextSheet.getLastRow();
    nextSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,numRows,3).setValues(values);
    sheet.deleteRows(startRow,numRows);
   } 
}
```

Even though I can see that it would only move a few columns instead of everything, I was hoping to get a start.

I also need to move the values inputted, instead of the results of formulas.

[This](http://www.jacorre.com/tutorial/google-spreadsheet-values-formulas/) shows how to get the values, but it's just storing them in a log, instead of actually putting them somewhere.

I'll keep googling tonight, and try to piece things together. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use formulas for all that. I've done things that are pretty similar to that with **FILTERS**.

Create a **VIEW PROJECT** sheet. In that tab, you have a cell with content validation that takes the project names (or dragon names) from the first sheet, then you can fill your VIEW PROJECT sheet cells with filters that will get the content according to the project you choose in that cell.

For example, in the cell **C4** of **Project1** sheet (dragon name), you put a validation to get the values from `'All Projects'!D3:D`

Then, in the other correspondent cells, you use filters, for example:

GETTING THE ID (`'Project1'!c6`):

```
= filter( 'All Projects'!E3:E; 'All Projects'!D3:D = $C$4)
```

With filters used correctly and some "selectboxes" (cells with validations) you can do what you want. believe me, its better than creating new tabs for each project.

Google apps scripts are awesome, but formulas are pretty powerfull too.

Obs: Rename your sheet Project1 to "View Project"

Obs2: In the first Sheet there are many merged cells that make some things difficult. As they are only merged for layout matters, I suggest unmerging them and removing the borders.

Hope that helps

Comment: The data in the All Projects things populate what will eventually be ten Project sheets, which you can reuse. I'm too lazy to keep making the sheets, so I was hoping to archive it.

I'll edit my post to clarify how I'm using the sheet, sorry.

I don't think this will help me, but thanks!

Comment: @wulfae, you wont keep making them. You will only select the dragon name and all content will change accordingly. Its faster than looking for the correct sheet. Add to that the fact that you will have to change your code for each column change in the first sheet, and you'll see that formulas for this case should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems with your code:

1 - You can't move merged cells, if you select those to move you'll get an Error, so numColumns should be:

`var numColumns = s.getLastColumn() - 1;`

2 - target range must be the same size as the copied one, so include the columns:

`var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns);`

3- Column 1 is merged, you can't move that, start from column 2:

`s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);`

If you want to move only the data but keep the formatting, use `copyTo()` and `clearContents()`.

Comment: Thank youuu! I will try this when I get home. Just to clarify, which version are you working off of?

Comment: First one, applicable to second one, but instead of checking if the range is in row 18, just move if ROW 18 is yes, or the user must have selected row 18 before issuing the command.

Comment: The data is moving! YAY! I've updated my post with what I have, because I must be doing the clearContents wrong. :S Any ideas on how to move the values, instead of the formulas?

Comment: @wulfae Use `getValues()` then `setValues()` to copy only the values.